# How to get the last day of month from a YearMonth date?

Tags: jodatime

I am going to convert a YearMonth date to a LocalDate which is going to be the last day for that month. So I need to use the toLocalDate(int i) method. How can I get the last day of that month using the yearMonth instance to pass it to that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with this solution:

> ```
>  yearMonth.toLocalDate(yearMonth.plusMonths(1).toLocalDate(1).minusDays(1).getDayOfMonth())
> ```

I need to get the first day of the next month and then deducting 1 day from it using minusDays(1) method.

Comment: Congrats! Can you mark your own answer as the solution please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Short of simply having an `array` of numbers, you could programmatically figure it out using something like the following:

```
if (month == 2 && year % 4 == 0)
    return 29;
else if (month == 2)
    return 28;
else {
    if (month > 7)
        month -= 1;
    if (month % 2 == 0) //Month number is even
        return 30;
    else
        return 31;
}
```

So to walk through this:

1. First you're checking to see if it's February and it's a leap year.
2. Next you're simply checking if it's February.
3. After that, you're looking to see if the month is August or later, since that's when the months with 31 days starts over. If that's the case, you basically change the month number from an even number or vice versa.
4. Finally, you run the month number (edited or not, depending if it's August or later) through to see if it's even or odd, ultimately deciding the last day.

Example: February, 2015. `month = 2` and `year = 2015`. `month` does equal `2` but `year % 4` equals `3`. End result, `return 28`.

Example 2: October, 2015. `month = 10` and `year = 2015`. `month` is greater than 7, so `month = 9`. `month` is odd, so end result, `return 31`.

Comment: It is wrong cause it will give you date like 1900-2-29

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue()` to get last day of current month and year.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        YearMonth ym = new YearMonth();
        System.out.println(ym);
        int dayCount = daysOfMonth(ym.getYear(), ym.getMonthOfYear());
        LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate(ym.getYear(), ym.getMonthOfYear(), dayCount);
        System.out.println(localDate);
    }

    public static int daysOfMonth(int year, int month) {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, 14, 12, 0, 0, 000);
        return dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
    }
}
```

Also simply you can change main method part(without changing daysOfMonth method)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    YearMonth ym = new YearMonth();
    System.out.println(ym);
    LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.toLocalDate(daysOfMonth(ym.getYear(), ym.getMonthOfYear()));
    System.out.println(endOfMonth);
}
```